# Query - Data Extension with Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I'm trying to combine a data extension which includes subscriber's information with a query activity to pull in clicks, views, etc for a jobID.

Ideally I would be able to filter from this combined information into a data extension to do some advance data filtering.

I have the following query but I'm running into an error when trying to save the query.

```
select 
s.EmailAddress 
from _Subscribers s 
inner join _click c on (
       s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid 
)
where JobID = 585614
```

An error occurred saving the definition:

> A problem occurred creating your query definition. Please contact
>   Customer Service for additional information. Name: data_view_test
>   External Key: 48e74a88-1bce-4262-9981-30b5bf2d9c2e Error saving the
>   Query field.Field 'Subscriber Key' is a required for the Target Data
>   Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query text.

I'm not sure what I need to do as i'm new with queries.

Answer (score 3):

It means just what the error message says:  Your query needs to return a `Subscriber Key` column, since it's required in your Target Data Extension.

If the Subscriber Key is an email address it can be something like this:

```
select 
s.EmailAddress 
, s.EmailAddress as [Subscriber Key]
from _Subscribers s 
inner join _click c on (
       s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid 
)
where JobID = 585614
```